# Adding an encryption layer in Angular Application

Tags: angular, typescript, encryption, public-key-encryption

The Goal is to create a encryption layer where requests and response are encrypted , so that entire application is more secure.
The approach we have finalized is RSA+AES, where we will generate a AES key for each session and encrypt it using RSA public key and share it with backend and the payload will be encrypted with generated session key. and backend will respond in encrypted format using the session key obtained

Would like to know the views on the above implementation any suggestions or improvement.

One change which could be done is key is generated from backed and initial request can be done to exchange keys.

Comment: Are you using angularjs (1.x version), or Angular (2.x and beyond)?

Comment: It's unclear what your proposed solution does compared to simply using TLS (https).

Comment: @PeterLaBanca angular 13

Comment: @Peter It ensures more security and avoid any unwanted trackerrs , lookers and avoid any potential data breach